# Mixing Spring Data JPASpecificationExecutor / QueryByDsl with Hibernate Full Text Search 6.0

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, hibernate-search

I have an entity say

```java
class Employee {
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String title;
    private String jobDescription; // Free Text
}
```

I can search/filter data on multiple fields when the following url is invoked

`http://localhost:8080/employee?name=Jack&jobDescritpion=developer`

This can be done without any code using the following repository

```java
public interface EmployeeRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Employee, Long>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Employee>, QuerydslBinderCustomizer<Employee>
```

The `QuerydslBinderCustomizer` will generate the `like` queries for all `String` fields using the following:

```java
@Override
default void customize(QuerydslBindings bindings, QEmployee employee) {
    bindings.bind(String.class)
        .first((StringPath path, String value) -> path.containsIgnoreCase(value));
}
```

This way I can get a basic text search capability for `jobDescription`

When the dataset gets huge, say 1 million, the `like` will kill the performance. The solution will be to index just the description field (or even all fields) to Lucene and use `Hibernate Search` such that for `jobDescrription` I can do:

```java
SearchResult<Employee> searchResult = searchSession.search(Employee.class)
    .where(f ->f.match()
        .field("jobDescription")
        .matching(keywords)
        .fuzzy()).fetch(offset,size);
```

Here on I have 2 choices:

1. Index `all fields` in Lucene
2. Index `only jobDescritpion` in Lucene

I am ok with both the options. The question is how can I integrate this with JPA such that the following url still works, only this time the query is built from the Hibernate Search index and executed by JPA:

`http://localhost:8080/employee?name=Jack&jobDescritpion=developer`

How to achieve this integration between `Hibernate Search` and `JPA` via `JPASpecification` or `QueryByDsl` or any other way?

Answer (score 0):

You really only have one choice, and it's to index all fields in Lucene. While relying on both a database `WHERE` and Lucene queries to implement a search query is possible, it really doesn't perform well, especially when using pagination.

Regarding how to use Hibernate Search queries via `JPASpecification` or `QueryByDsl`... I'm not overly familiar with this technology, so take this with a grain of salt.

But I know there's been an attempt to integrate Hibernate Search 5 (the older version) into Spring with the [Snowdrop](https://github.com/snowdrop/spring-data-snowdrop) project. I assume you would have to do the same for Hibernate Search 6.

As to QueryDSL, as far as I can tell it's still relying on the older Hibernate Search 5, so it cannot be used with Hibernate Search 6 until someone who needs it decides to upgrade it.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know an example of `QueryDsl` with `HibernateSearch 5` and spring data `repositories`?

Comment: I looked at this : https://github.com/snowdrop/spring-data-snowdrop/blob/master/documentation/src/main/asciidoc/reference/data-snowdrop.adoc It does not provide a way to use Predicates to do a dynamic must() based on the query parameters from the url. Something that Querydsl and Spring Data provide out of the box with `QuerydslPredicateExecutor`